# What's the name of the 3-Byte variable-width Unicode Encoding Scheme?

Tags: unicode, encoding

Hi all I was wondering what's the name of the Unicode Encoding Scheme whereby:

Code Points U+1 to U+7F is represented using one byte:

```
   Byte 1: 0xxxxxxx
```

Code Points U+80 to U+3FFF is represented using two bytes:

```
   Byte 1: 0xxxxxxx
   Byte 2: 1xxxxxxx
```

Code Points U+4000 to U+10FFFF is represented using three bytes:

```
   Byte 1: 0xxxxxxx
   Byte 2: 1xxxxxxx
   Byte 3: 1xxxxxxx
```

From what I can see, this scheme beats UTF-8 because only one to three bytes is required to represent each CodePoint (UTF-8 requires 1 to 4 bytes to represent a single CodePoint), and I was wondering if there's an official name for this encoding.

Comment: I have never heard of this encoding but it has serious disadvantages so I'm not so sure the size savings are worth it.

Comment: @Celada Heys could you elaborate on the *serious disadvantages* ?

Comment: Unlike UTF-8, you don't know the length of a character representation in advance. So you cannot interpret the latest character in a stream unless you are sure that it's the very end of the stream.

Comment: @Tanriol This is not a serious disadvantage. It's the same deal with the comparison between fixed-width encoding (ability to know the number of characters even before examining them) vs variable-width encoding (needs to read the characters before knowing the length)

Comment: if (next-2-bytes-start-with-1) { process all 3 bytes } else if (next-1-byte-start-with-1) {process 2 bytes} else {process 1 byte}

Comment: @Pacerier With UTF-8 you know the length of the character after reading the first byte, therefore at the end of a stream you know if the character is complete without knowing if the you're at the end of the stream. Also, byte oriented string searching may give bad results with this encoding because a character may appear as the prefix of another character, unlike with UTF-8.

Comment: This encoding isn't ASCII compatible (e.g. the byte 0x20 can occur even when there are no spaces), whereas UTF-8 is. This means that UTF-8 is far more useful in practice. Pacerier's encoding also lacks robustness in the face of errors -- in ASCII, UTF-8 and UTF-16 corruption of a character never damages adjacent characters, but in Pacerier's encoding characters either side may be damaged.

Comment: @tialaramex I don't get why everyone wants to be ASCII compatible. This is no longer 10 years ago. Isn't encoding all about treating the input as a couple of bytes, sending it over the wire, then decoding it into actual characters? The reasons you gave was with UTF8, we know the length of the character after reading the first byte. I don't see it as an advantage at all if we can guarantee that the byte stream is *complete*. I also don't understand why does the encoding itself have to be the *layer* which guards against errors. If I pass you 'abcd', and there's corruption, and

Comment: @bames53 {cont above} you give me 'abd' instead of 'abcd', that's an error nonetheless. The network *layer* should be the one that guards against these problems. By the time it reaches the encoding *layer*, it isn't too unreasonable to say that this stream of bytes are uncorrupted is it?

Comment: The issue with ASCII compatibility is that there's a lot of code that works with ASCII compatible encodings. Also the problem with some characters appearing as prefixes to other characters isn't just ASCII compatibility, it's simply more work to write code to handle that. Another advantage to UTF-8 is that is common and widely supported. If you're looking to save space just use compression instead of trying to introduce a new encoding and writing all new code to deal with it. For example, most webservers already compress the resources they serve up.

Comment: @Pacerier: bames53 is right. There is too much legacy code still in active use to throw away ASCII compatibility. For instance, most Internet protocols that are actively in use (FTP, HTTP, email, etc) are still largely ASCII based (especially email - there are still 7bit gateways in use), but do define protocol extensions to allow non-ASCII character encodings when both parties support them.  UTF-8 and many Ansi encodings require 8bit support in infrastructures.  That is why things like MIME, UTF-7, etc were created to pass 8bit data around in 7bit systems.

Comment: @pacerier: You could reduce the lookahead requirements by changing the scheme slightly: One byte 0xxxxxxx, two bytes 1xxxxxxx 0xxxxxxx, three bytes 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 0xxxxxxx.

Comment: You ask for the name of "the Unicode Encoding Scheme whereby..." [snip]. This seems to say you saw this scheme mentioned and named somewhere, it wasn't something you just made up.  I've not been able to find any trace of it.  Where and when did you see it mentioned? Can you give some context, please?

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt no I didn't see this scheme before, but its a simple scheme so I'd thought that it already existed and asked for its name (to be able to google or wiki it for more info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual question appears to be, "what's the name" of this encoding. While it's hard tp prove a negative, I'll go out on a limb and say, no-one else has published and named this encoding. You just invented it.  Thus, your answer is that this encoding has no name. Invent a name for it, and that will be its name.

You also add, "From what I can see, this scheme beats UTF-8...". There's been a discussion about that claim in the comments. If you want to post this as a separate question, e.g. "Is this encoding scheme better than UTF-8", that would be another matter. Hint: if you do so, consider which criteria you use to measure "better". Do you think your new encoding scheme is better than UTF-8 *according to UTF-8's own design criteria*?

Comment: Cool, I'll accept this as answer until someone else proves a negative.

Comment: You are very fair, @Pacerier. Some people might just ignore the answers in this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of needlessly resurrecting a very old question, and just for the sake of completeness, I'd say this is a slight variation of what is sometimes called "VarInt" (see for example [this from ProtoBuf wire format](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#varints)). It is also similar to [VLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) (which has quite a few variations and many other names).

The difference is that VarInt has the msb set on all bytes except the last, but OP's encoding has the msb set on all bytes but the first.

I'd argue that VarInt encoding is better, because it's easier to decode (and maybe more robust) when the decoder encounters the first byte(s) of an encoded value: it can know that more bytes are needed without waiting to look at the next bytes.

I must note that while the ProtoBuf usage might not have been well publicized in 2012 (when this question was posted), the other similar (or identical) encodings have been in use for some time (see the Wikipedia article.)